# How i can make background color of my links match my border

Tags: html, css

So is the any way to have my links background color extend so that it covers everything inside my borders

Heres what it looks right now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM6Wj.png

html code

```
<style>
    a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
background-color:#CCFFFF;}
</style>

        <ul style="margin-right:20px; margin-left:-25px">
    <h2>
        <li class="sidebarlinks"><a href="test3.html">Kappa</a></li>
        <br>
        <li class="sidebarlinks"><a href="test2.html">Banana</a></li>
        <br>
        <li class="sidebarlinks"><a href="test1.html">Energydrink</a></li>
    </h2>
    </ul>
```

css code

```
a:link {
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
font-size:35px;
background-color:#9AFEFF
}

a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebarlinks {
border:2px solid black;
border-radius:10px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the display property to "block" for the "a" elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/tVP87/1/

```
.sidebarlinks a {
    display: block;
}
```

The advantage of this method is that the whole area will be hoverable AND clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first define your area for the clickable button first. And also you have a lot of unneeded code placed in there. Don't h2 li's. Use font/text styling. Also don't use 2 forms of CSS. You have it inline and separated from what I see. And what's the point of having the right and left margins for the ul??

It should be somehting like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8sFJ/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="sidebarlinks"><a href="test3.html">Kappa</a></li>
    <li class="sidebarlinks"><a href="test2.html">Banana</a></li>
    <li class="sidebarlinks"><a href="test1.html">Energydrink</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    font-size:200%;
    width:300px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background-color:#9AFEFF
}
a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    font-size:35px;

}
a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebarlinks {
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:10px
}
li:hover {
    background-color:#CCFFFF;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background colour on the LI rather than the link. That should do it...

[See](http://cdpn.io/hwuJb)

HTH :)

Comment: You've got massive areas which look like they're clickable (because the colour changes) but aren't

Comment: @Gareth, the "clickability" is addressed in a different way, but background color extension is solved

Comment: @MaxMalyk - If the clickability is addressed in the correct way, then the background colour will just work without needing it set on the LI

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the background color transparent  `background-color: transparent;` or do not use any background color

Answer (score 0):

As @LDJ already pointed out, you can just change the `<li>` hover event to match the `<a>` hover event.

OR

You could have the `<a>` change when `<li>` is hovered.

```
li.sidebarlinks:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
li.sidebarlinks:hover > a {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

I would also avoid spanning your `<h2>` tag over other tags as it could cause confusion in your SEO.
    
        ul {
            margin-right:20px; margin-left:-25px
        }

```
    a:link {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:black;
        font-size:35px;
        background-color:#9AFEFF
    }

    a:visited {
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .sidebarlinks {
        border:2px solid black;
        border-radius:10px
    }


    li.sidebarlinks:hover {
        background: #9AFEFF;
    }

    li.sidebarlinks:hover > a {
        background: #9AFEFF;
    }

</style>
<ul>
    <li class="sidebarlinks"><h2><a href="test3.html">Kappa</a></h2></li>
    <br>
    <li class="sidebarlinks"><h2><a href="test2.html">Banana</a></h2></li>
    <br>
    <li class="sidebarlinks"><h2><a href="test1.html">Energydrink</a></h2></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ug2Sc/

Code:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    font-size:35px;
    background-color:#9AFEFF
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-color:#CCFFFF;
}
.sidebarlinks a {
    display: block;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.sidebarlinks {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
```